# Publicar sitio asp.net

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, iis

quiero publicar en hostig mi proyecto de web pero no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo. Alguien me puede dar una mano?
Es una aplicacion de asp.net y sql server 2008.
Gracias !

Comment: Hola Yamila. Esa pregunta es muy muy amplia, demasiado para el formato de este sitio. Te animo a repasar el [dentro de ayuda en cuanto a cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking), y en particular para este caso: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes subir tu sitio a Microsoft Azure, ingresando al siguiente link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/try/app-service/

En cualquier caso, necesitas contratar un servicio de hosting con soporte para IIS (Internet Information Services).

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Exitos!